# How to set a script as Background of a concrete <section>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I am using Bootstrap for a one-page website project. This website is divided in 4 parts, each one inside a 'section' with its own background color/image and content.
For one of these sections (the first one), which occupies the whole screen and has a 'Navbar' at the top and some headers inside, I would like to set a script as the background and not a simple image or solid color as in the other sections.

For this, I would like to know how to set a JavaScript code as the background, without affecting any other item inside the same section and being able to see the text over this background element.

This is the concrete script that I would like to set as background (got it from codePen.io): http://jsfiddle.net/oleg_korol/a1bxr5ua/1/

Here is the code:

```
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),

    opts = {

        len: 20,
        count: 50,
        baseTime: 10,
        addedTime: 10,
        dieChance: .05,
        spawnChance: 1,
        sparkChance: .1,
        sparkDist: 10,
        sparkSize: 2,

        color: 'hsl(hue,100%,light%)',
        baseLight: 50,
        addedLight: 10, // [50-10,50+10]
        shadowToTimePropMult: 6,
        baseLightInputMultiplier: .01,
        addedLightInputMultiplier: .02,

        cx: w / 2,
        cy: h / 2,
        repaintAlpha: .04,
        hueChange: .1
    },

    tick = 0,
    lines = [],
    dieX = w / 2 / opts.len,
    dieY = h / 2 / opts.len,

    baseRad = Math.PI * 2 / 6;

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

function loop() {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    ++tick;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,alp)'.replace('alp', opts.repaintAlpha);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

    if (lines.length < opts.count && Math.random() < opts.spawnChance) lines.push(new Line);

    lines.map(function (line) {
        line.step();
    });
}

function Line() {

    this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.reset = function () {

    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.addedX = 0;
    this.addedY = 0;

    this.rad = 0;

    this.lightInputMultiplier = opts.baseLightInputMultiplier + opts.addedLightInputMultiplier * Math.random();

    this.color = opts.color.replace('hue', tick * opts.hueChange);
    this.cumulativeTime = 0;

    this.beginPhase();
}
Line.prototype.beginPhase = function () {

    this.x += this.addedX;
    this.y += this.addedY;

    this.time = 0;
    this.targetTime = (opts.baseTime + opts.addedTime * Math.random()) | 0;

    this.rad += baseRad * (Math.random() < .5 ? 1 : -1);
    this.addedX = Math.cos(this.rad);
    this.addedY = Math.sin(this.rad);

    if (Math.random() < opts.dieChance || this.x > dieX || this.x < -dieX || this.y > dieY || this.y < -dieY) this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.step = function () {

    ++this.time;
    ++this.cumulativeTime;

    if (this.time >= this.targetTime) this.beginPhase();

    var prop = this.time / this.targetTime,
        wave = Math.sin(prop * Math.PI / 2),
        x = this.addedX * wave,
        y = this.addedY * wave;

    ctx.shadowBlur = prop * opts.shadowToTimePropMult;
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = this.color.replace('light', opts.baseLight + opts.addedLight * Math.sin(this.cumulativeTime * this.lightInputMultiplier));
    ctx.fillRect(opts.cx + (this.x + x) * opts.len, opts.cy + (this.y + y) * opts.len, 2, 2);

    if (Math.random() < opts.sparkChance) ctx.fillRect(opts.cx + (this.x + x) * opts.len + Math.random() * opts.sparkDist * (Math.random() < .5 ? 1 : -1) - opts.sparkSize / 2, opts.cy + (this.y + y) * opts.len + Math.random() * opts.sparkDist * (Math.random() < .5 ? 1 : -1) - opts.sparkSize / 2, opts.sparkSize, opts.sparkSize)
}
loop();

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {

    w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    opts.cx = w / 2;
    opts.cy = h / 2;

    dieX = w / 2 / opts.len;
    dieY = h / 2 / opts.len;
});
//@ sourceURL=pen.js
```

Thanks a lot!

- Original piece of code from: http://codepen.io/towc/pen/mJzOWJ
  by Matei Copot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: I have edited the answer for @Oleg and +1 it again.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLyndem and @paulie-d!

Comment: I've edited the question explaining a little bit more in detail my problem. Hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: glad you liked my animation. Where is it being used? Is there a copyright on it? You should have asked permission first, just saying

Comment: @towc Indeed a really nice animation ;) It is not being used anywhere. I just used the code for testing purposes. I hope that's fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an `iframe` and placing it as an `absolute` element with full body width and height like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="iframe"><iframe name="result" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin" frameborder="0" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/oleg_korol/a1bxr5ua/1/show/"></iframe></div>
            <!--Your page content-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#iframe {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/kkLLxkxk/2/

And here is a StackOverflow snippet with above codes:

```css
html, body {
        margin:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
}

iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#iframe {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="iframe"><iframe name="result" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin" frameborder="0" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/oleg_korol/a1bxr5ua/1/show/"></iframe></div>
```

**WITHOUT IFRAME:**

If you want to use the canvas as the background-image for the whole page, then the current code that you are using should work fine with `width` and `height` defined:

```
canvas {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

However if you want it as the background-image only for a certain div, then you can just add a `position:relative;` property to the parent div like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas-box">
    <canvas id=c></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas-box {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for adding canvas as background for a specific div: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/a1bxr5ua/5/

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Please provide a legitimate reason for the downvote so I can edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: iFrames are generally frowned upon with the new basis of responsive web design and is not a very likeable solution. I did not downvote, because the answer works, but I would not like to see this implemented on any website.

Comment: @Nicholas Agreed. But the OP simply asked for a solution to use the script as a background and this answered the question :) If he had asked for a solution that required it to be responsive or SEO friendly, or for that matter, not an iframe then yes I agree that this answer is not the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assuming we want something responsive and SEO friendly, what would be the best way to do it?